# ListBox.ItemsSource binding in code and in xaml

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemssource

I wrote simple code like

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Names …
public Window1()
{
    PutInDataIntoNames();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.listBox1.ItemsSource = Names;
}
```

and in xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="10,11,10,16"
         Name="listBox1"
         Background="Black" 
         Foreground="Orange" 
         />
</Grid>
```

Then I wanted to set ItemsSource property in xaml. In order to do that I wrote the following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work. Could you explain why and how to do that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in code behind

```
public Window1() 
{ 
    PutInDataIntoNames(); 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    DataContext = this;
}
```

and in XAML

```
<Grid> 
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
         Margin="10,11,10,16" 
         Name="listBox1" 
         Background="Black"  
         Foreground="Orange"   
         /> 
</Grid>
```

Ideally you should follow MVVM design to isolate data from code behind.

Comment: OK. but i would prefer to write it in xaml like
   <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

It is often a bit disappointing that sometimes I dont't need to explicitly set up DataContext while sometimes I must.

Answer (score 11):

If you only specify the binding path the binding engine will try to navigate the path starting from the current `DataContext` so `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}"` does not work like this, there are a lot of different things to keep in mind especially when doing more complex things.

The single most important article that everyone who is new to DataBinding should read is the [Data Binding Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

To get back to your binding, if you want to do it completely in XAML you can do that as well, you just need to make the Window your source somehow, either by referencing it directly or relatively or by setting it up as the DataContext.

1 - Direct Reference:

```
<Window Name="Window"
        ...>
    <Grid> 
            <ListBox ...
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Names}"
                     .../>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

2 - Relative Reference

```
    <Grid> 
            <ListBox ...
                     ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Names}"
                     .../>
    </Grid>
```

3 - Setting up the DataContext

```
<Window ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <Grid> 
            <ListBox ...
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}"
                     .../>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer. One element difficult to find is the way the XAML binding for the source must be expressed in the `Window` instance: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"`. It's the XAML equivalent of c# `DataContext = this`, but deserves it's own explanation, which is difficult to find online (and is apparently missing from MSDN documentation, all examples being based on [a source being a resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-specify-the-binding-source), never on a CLR object created in the code-behind).

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your `Names` might be a field. You can ONLY bind to public properties